# How to open a file on top of display using powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to create a script that notifies me each time there is a change in a specific directory.

I want to make sure I see the notification, so I would like to pop the log file over all display once a new notification is registerd.
this is the script I'm using:

```
$filewatcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
#Mention the folder to monitor
$filewatcher.Path = "C:\Users\zeevh\Downloads\"
$filewatcher.Filter = "*.*"
#include subdirectories $true/$false
$filewatcher.IncludeSubdirectories = $true
$filewatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $true  

$writeaction = { $path = $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath
                 $changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType
                 $logline = "$(Get-Date), $changeType, $path"
                 Add-content "C:\Users\zeevh\Documents\FileWatcher_log.txt" -value $logline
Invoke-Item "C:\Users\zeevh\Documents\FileWatcher_log.txt"
               }    

Register-ObjectEvent $filewatcher "Created" -Action $writeaction
Register-ObjectEvent $filewatcher "Changed" -Action $writeaction
Register-ObjectEvent $filewatcher "Deleted" -Action $writeaction
Register-ObjectEvent $filewatcher "Renamed" -Action $writeaction
while ($true) {sleep 5}
```

right now I use 'Invoke-Item'(also tried 'start') command, but it just opens the file without bringing it to the front.
Is there a why to do this

Comment: What if you use: `Add-Type -AssemblyNamePresentationFramework` and then `[System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show('Hello')`? It won't open the logfile, but it will show a persistent notification. Can be made always on top using `$form.TopMost = $True`.

Comment: @LPChip now I get a message but still not on top. Not sure I put the form.topmost in the right place, I just placed it under the show command

Comment: You must place it above. The messagebox will halt the script until ok is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use a toast notification vs your effort. See/use the BurntToast module with your FileSystemWatcher code. This is why notifications in Windows exist.

```
Find-Module -Name '*toast*' | 
Format-List
# Results
<#


Name                       : BurntToast
Version                    : 0.8.3
Type                       : Module
Description                : Module for creating and displaying Toast Notifications on Microsoft Windows 10.
Author                     : Joshua (Windos) King
CompanyName                : Windos
Copyright                  : (c) 2015 Joshua (Windos) King. All rights reserved.
PublishedDate              : 04-Oct-20 21:26:21
...
#>
```

> Module Monday: BurntToast
>
> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TwZjr66yfc8&feature=youtu.be